# How to get X and Y of detected circles?

Tags: opencv, android

I want to extract circles in and Image, So I extract them with below code:

```java
Mat circles = new Mat();
Imgproc.HoughCircles(adaptiveThresh, circles, Imgproc.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.0, (double) adaptiveThresh.rows() / 40, 100.0, 30.0, 20, 30);
```

And then I iterate through them with below code:

```java
for (int x = 0; x < circles.cols(); x++) {
    double[] c = circles.get(0, x);
    Point center = new Point(Math.round(c[0]), Math.round(c[1]));
    int radius = (int) Math.round(c[2]);
    Imgproc.circle(source, center, radius, new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
}
```

But I want to sort them from topleft to bottom right, And the problem is I can not access the `x` and `y` of the `circles`!
How may I sort them based on row from top left to bottom right?

Comment: It can be easily caclucated e.g: `x= center.x - radius, y = center.y-radius`

Comment: @BahramdunAdil thanks! but how can I sort `circles`?

Comment: Posted the answer, you should try it. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is can be confusing. As it can be (1) sort distance to the circle to the top left of the image.  (2)sort the distance from top left of each circle to top left of the image corner?

I assume you want to find the circle which is most close to top left case (1).

Here is my response.

From the C++ sample( i guess you are using android, not very familiar). You can convert using my sample code below.

```
   for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
      {
          Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
          int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
          // circle center
          circle( src, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
          // circle outline
          circle( src, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
       }
```

the center should be the point you want.

To sort them from top left to bottom right using city block distance you just have to

```
void sort_points (std::vector<Vec3f> &array)
{
    std::cout<<"Elements in the array: "<<array.size()<<std::endl;

    //comparisons will be done n times
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        //compare elemet to the next element, and swap if condition is true
        for(int j = 0; j < array.size() - 1; j++)
        {   
            if ((array[j][0]+array[j][1]) > (array[j+1][0]+ array[j+1][1])
                Swap(&array[j], &array[j+1]);
        }
    }
}



int main(argc,argv)
// ...................//do your stuff

    vector<Vec3f> circles; //detected circle

   // ... //do the detection 

    sort_points(circles);
    //circles here is fully sorted from city block distance
    std::cout<<circles<<std::endl; // print out all sorted circile

// ...................//do your stuff

}
```

if it is 2nd case just change if by

```
if ((array[j][0]+array[j][1]-2*array[j][2]) > (array[j+1][0]+ array[j+1][1]-2*array[j+1][2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

1. First, declare a Circle class (for encapsulation the circle properties for sorting purpose)

> ```
> class Circle {
>     int cX;
>     int cY;
>     int radius;
>     double distance;
> }
> ```

2. Now iterate over the HoughCircles result, and create a Circle instance and then add it to the List

> ```
> List<Circle> circleList = new ArrayList<>();
> //start point, it is used to calculate the distance
> Point p1 = new Point(0, 0);
> for (int x = 0; x < circles.cols(); x++) {
>     double[] c = circles.get(0, x);
>     Point center = new Point(Math.round(c[0]), Math.round(c[1]));
>     int radius = (int) Math.round(c[2]);
>     Imgproc.circle(source, center, radius, new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
>
>     // here create the Circle instance
>     Circle circle = new Circle();
>     cricle.cX = center.x;
>     circle.cY = center.y;
>     circle.radius= radius;
>
>     double D = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(abs(p1.x - circles.x), 2) + Math.pow(abs(p1.y - circles.y), 2));
>     circle.distance = D;
>
>     // add the circle instance to the list
>     circleList.add(circle);
> }
> ```

3. Now sort the circles in the list, use distance from small to bigger

> ```
> circleList.sort(new Comparator<File>() {
>     @Override
>     public int compare(Circle c1, Circle c2) {
>         return Double.compare(c1.distance, c2.distance);
>     }
> });
> ```

Now you can do what you want with circles list.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: What do you mean by don't work, what is the error? I did not compile the code, I directly wrote it in the answer so it may have compile time or runtime error, but you can follow the steps I have shown in the answer, take the idea and go step by step.